# Python MacOS Error: Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am trying to run a python script on my mac but

**"Unable to revert mtime: /Library/Fonts"**

keeps popping up when i run the program. i have the latest version of python installed as well as **matplotlib**. i am very new to python so i do not know what the issue is but here is the snippet of the code:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json
import datetime

with open('ELIX.json') as json_file:
data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 49):

you need to have libmagic

```
brew install libmagic
```

Comment: this answer helped me solve the same problem.

Comment: can you please explain more about it?

Comment: It worked for me as well. Thanks!
I was trying to use Imagemagick's convert utility. And that's when I got this error. After installing libmagic, the error went away.

Comment: Care to explain it a bit? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

In my situation, I had to restore the fonts that came with my system. To do so:

1. Open up the Font Book app
2. Go to `File`
3. Click `Restore Standard Fonts`

Video: https://www.loom.com/share/379ad4f9539d4730af75039623027888

Comment: This solved  my issue.

Comment: After 30 years with macs, there are still things I've never even heard of apparently!